# Where to get feedback from professional comic artists?

Tags: comics

I'm looking for a website where I can get technical advices from people in the profession.

Comment: There are a lot of talented people in industry that hang out on conceptart.org and cghub.com forums. I don't know if you will find comic artist pros giving feedback all the time though. Those guys are usually pretty busy.

Comment: @Alexei I don't see any category in the forums related to comics or cartoons so I feel those sites would be the wrong place to ask. How come I can't find a dedicated site ?! Even Manga Studio doesn't have a forum !

Comment: For cartoon-style comics, you are right, it might not be the best place. I thought you meant Marvel-style comics. But hey, there is a really nice thread on CGHub called "Digital comics - the pros" in the Sequential Art & Storyboarding forum. It's a cool new approach to storytelling if you want to do comics for the web. Well good luck, and sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @Alexei I posted on CGHub, waiting for replies. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% professional members, but you could try: http://www.thecomicforums.com

You could also sign in for the Area 51 proposed pages, for example:

Making Comics
Proposed Q&A site for artists, writers, comics makers, on all supports, with all narrative styles!
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9271/making-comics

Art Creation
Proposed Q&A site for artists, painters, drawers, caricaturists, illustrators, cartoonists, graphic artists, engravers, sculptors, etc. Basically art techniques and methodologies.
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7250/art-creation

I'd also say http://www.deviantart.com/ , because it has great artists and perhaps you can contact some of them. I'm sure lot's of people would give you their opinion. And don't rule out comic geeks, they can give you an expert's idea too. Good luck!

Comment: I'm waiting for thecomicforums.com's admin to validate my account (kind of thing that don't always happen). I've sent my request to join 2 groups at deviantart, but this site has no forum so not sure how I'll ask my questions. Would be cool if the stackexchange's comic sites were already launched.